# onPostExecute of AsyncTask not called

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I'm relatively new to Android app development and wonder what I'm doing wrong. I have an AsyncTask that connects to my web server with username and password and returns the user dataset as json object. Unfortunately I can't get the json string, because onPostExecute() in my AsyncHttpReading class doesn't seem to get called. Why?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.alphavoice.sampleproject;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.alphavoice.sampleproject.community.user.User;
import com.alphavoice.sampleproject.util.HttpReader;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences appPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean isLoggedIn = (appPrefs.getInt("userId", 0) != 0) ? true : false;

        if (isLoggedIn) {    
            renderCommunityView();
        }
        else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final Button btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
            final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
            final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);

            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                    String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

                    String loginUrl = "http://example.com/websrv/get_user.php?username=" + username + "&password=" + password;

                    AsyncHttpReading httpReading = new AsyncHttpReading();

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                        int corePoolSize = 60;
                        int maximumPoolSize = 80;
                        int keepAliveTime = 10;

                        BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(maximumPoolSize);
                        Executor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, workQueue);
                        // httpReading.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, loginUrl);
                        httpReading.executeOnExecutor(threadPoolExecutor, loginUrl);
                    }
                    else {
                        httpReading.execute(loginUrl);
                    }

                    if (httpReading.getLoggedInUser() != null) {
                        // renderCommunityView();
                        btnLogin.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                    else {
                        // wrong combination of username & password => try again
                        etUsername.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 204, 204));
                        etPassword.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 204, 204));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void renderCommunityView() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_community);
    }

    private class AsyncHttpReading extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private String response = "";
        private User loggedInUser = null;

        public AsyncHttpReading() { }

        public String getResponse() {
            return response;
        }

        public User getLoggedInUser() {
            return loggedInUser;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            HttpReader httpReader = new HttpReader(urls[0]);
            response = httpReader.getResponse();

            return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject userData = new JSONObject(this.getResponse()).getJSONObject("0");

                if (userData != null) {
                    loggedInUser = new User(userData);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("SAMPLEPROJECT", "Could not parse json data!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HttpReader.java**

```
package com.alphavoice.sampleproject.util;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.util.Log;

public class HttpReader {
    private String url = "";

    public HttpReader(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getURL() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        URL urlObj = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        // http request
        try {
            urlObj = new URL(url);

            connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("SAMPLEPROJECT", "Could not connect to web server!");
        }

        // read stream
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlObj.openStream()));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            int read = 0;

            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1) {
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 
            }

            reader.close();

            return buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("SAMPLEPROJECT", "Could not open stream!");
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
package com.alphavoice.sampleproject.community.user;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class User {
    public User(JSONObject dataset) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Add logs messages and then try to find onpostExecute is getting called or not?

Comment: @NehaK Already tried logging it (without success).

Comment: Try to execute asyncTask with normal execute method.